# Unable to edit or delete own comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I'm unable to edit or delete my own comments on questions and answers.

I would suggest a long press on comment to display a menu to edit, delete own comments, **in place of** the "vote up" option - *as you can't vote on your own comment anyway*.

Comment: @Bart Removed all of the prefixes - however, at first glance at titles from the home page, one might mistake them for the sites instead of the app (like this question).

Comment: Then clarify the situation in your question. That should suffice.

Comment: That's why you have the android-app tag :) Are you saing that when you open the comment menu on a comment of your own, you don't get the delete (and possibly edit) option?

Comment: @balpha yes, I'm sure the "Vote Up" is the only option for comments, even my own, not due to the 5-min comment edit rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 0.1.6 will have an option to edit or delete for comments that you have created.  Moderators will have a full comment menu with all actions.

[image: comment options]